# How do I make a class method a coroutine?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20, c++-coroutine

How do I make a class method a coroutine? Here's a small example. Here I am trying to create a coroutine from a class method, but the compiler throws the following error:

> error: unable to find the promise type for this coroutine
> 52 | std::vector vec = co_await awaitable_func1();

How do I properly set up coroutine_traits for methods?

```
 auto awaitable_func1() {
        struct Awaitable {
            std::vector<int> vec;
    
            bool await_ready() { return false; }
    
            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coroutine) {
                vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                coroutine.resume();
            }
    
            auto await_resume() {
                return vec;
            }
        };
        return Awaitable{};
    }
    
    
    class Coroutine {
    public:
        void call(int);
    };
    
    struct Promise {
        Promise(Coroutine){}
        void get_return_object() {}
    
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() { return {}; }
    
        void return_void() {}
    
        void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
    };
    
    
    template<>
    struct std::coroutine_traits<void, Coroutine, int> {
        using promise_type = Promise;
    };
    
    
    void Coroutine::call(int a) {
        std::vector<int> vec = co_await awaitable_func1();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << vec[i] + a << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    
    int main() {
        Coroutine a;
        a.call(5);
        return 0;
    };
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a coroutine to return `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the ethics of returning `void`, the following changes are needed to make GCC compile this:

1. You're passing the wrong `Coroutine` type as the `*this` parameter. It needs to be a reference:

   ```
   struct std::coroutine_traits<void, Coroutine&, int> {
   ```
2. `final_suspend` must be `noexcept`:

   ```
   std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
   ```
3. The promise constructor must be invocable with either 0 arguments or with all parameters of the coroutine:

   ```
   Promise(Coroutine& this_, int& a){} // Option 1, take by value if you want to copy, use const as desired
   Promise(){} // Option 2, applicable if you don't need the parameters
   ```

As far as I can tell from the standard text, these three are correct errors.