# Writing coroutine_traits for member coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

How do we write `coroutine_traits` for coroutines which are member functions?

Here's an example: let's say that I want all functions that receive `my_tag` and return `my_result<type>` to become coroutines which use `my_promise`.

I create a specialization to tell the compiler to use `my_promise<type>` if the signature matches:

```cpp
namespace std { // or std::experimental, depending on the compiler + version 
    template<class type, class... arguments>
    struct coroutine_traits<my_result<type>, my_tag, arguments...> {
        using promise_type = my_promise<type>;
    };
}
```

Now all (free standing) functions that has the signature of `my_result<type> f (my_tag, ...);` will be transformed into coroutines by the compiler.
But this doesn't work for member functions, and as such for coroutine-lambdas:

```cpp
auto coro = [](my_tag) -> my_result<int>{
    co_return 1;
};

coro({}); // will fail to compile, or will use a different coroutine-promise that matches this signature.
```

[cpp-reference addresses it:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_traits)

> If the coroutine is a non-static member function, then the first type
> in Args... is the type of the implicit object parameter, and the rest
> are parameter types of the function (if any).

So in order to fix this issue, I can provide an overload:

```cpp
namespace std { // or std::experimental, depending on the compiler + version 
    template<class type, class class_type class... arguments>
    struct coroutine_traits<my_result<type>, class_type&, my_tag, arguments...> {
        using promise_type = my_promise<type>;
    };
}
```

With this fix, `class_type&` acts as the `*this` parameter and `coro({})` rightfully chooses the right specialization for its coroutine promise.
However, this is a bad fix, because this specialization can "catch" unrelated types:

```cpp
my_result<int> coro(std::string&, my_tag);
```

This function will become a coroutine which uses `my_promise<int>` even though it doesn't exactly match our intention:
We want free standing functions and member function that return `my_result` and receive `my_tag` as the first argument to become coroutines that use `my_promise`.
free standing functions that return `my_result` but do not receive `my_tag` as the first argument should be deduced to use other specialization of coroutine_traits, or fail to compile,
if there isn't any.

How can we do this? what is the correct way to specify `coroutine_traits` so it applies to member functions and not free standing functions that receive random argument?

thanks.

related:

[How do I make a class method a coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210278/how-do-i-make-a-class-method-a-coroutine)

Comment: I think you're stuck. There doesn't appear to be a way to distinguish the two cases purely by templating. What you can do is make `my_tag` a private type to your class, so that is becomes impossible for free functions to mention it. (Private types are still allowed in template specializations.)

Comment: @RaymondChen So I figured.. thanks anyway